# Wordpress: Table creation function fails

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a new mysql table using wordpress hooks. My code:

```
// this code is inside the main plugin file with the commented header
// other code in this file works as expected.

  // create grid table
  function createGridTable() {
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $createGridTableQuery = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'priceGrids (
      gridId mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY  (gridId),
    ) $charset_collate;';
    // run the built query statement
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $createGridTableQuery );
    // $wpdb->query($createGridTableQuery);
  }

  function runActivationFunctions () {
    createGridTable();
    // createLinkTable();
  }
  register_activation_hook(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), 'runActivationFunctions');
```

After disabling and reactivating the plugin mysql shows this:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_wptest2     |
+-----------------------+
| wp_commentmeta        |
| wp_comments           |
| wp_links              |
| wp_options            |
| wp_postmeta           |
| wp_posts              |
| wp_term_relationships |
| wp_term_taxonomy      |
| wp_termmeta           |
| wp_terms              |
| wp_testCreateViaCli   | // created via cli
| wp_usermeta           |
| wp_users              |
+-----------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following this guide for the syntax hasn't seemed to fix the issue: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

```
// example code
 global $wpdb;

 $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

 $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (   id mediumint(9) NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,   time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT
 NULL,   name tinytext NOT NULL,   text text NOT NULL,   url
 varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (id) )
 $charset_collate;";

 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' ); dbDelta(
 $sql );
```

Does anyone see the mistake in my code? I think I'm following the rules but no table is being generated via wordpress hook.

Not sure if it's relevant but I get this on every page load to the wordpress site, in the browser console:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code so i think you will able to add table.

```
function createGridTable() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'priceGrids ';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $createGridTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name  (
      gridId mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY  (gridId),
    ) $charset_collate;";
    // run the built query statement
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $createGridTableQuery );
    // $wpdb->query($createGridTableQuery);
  }

  function runActivationFunctions () {
    createGridTable();
    // createLinkTable();
  }
  register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'runActivationFunctions');
```

Tested and works

Comment: Hmm, there must be some other issue on my end then. I am imcluding a console error I get during plugin reactivation.

Comment: Disable all all extensions in chrome://extensions
Enable extensions one by one to detect which one is presenting de issue.

Comment: Thanks found the erroneous plugin. It wasn't causing the issue though, I keep trying to reactivate but the new table doesn't appear.